# When are local licenses assigned?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Xbox Marketplace purchases come with [two licenses](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/marketplace-and-purchasing/download-content): **system**  and **local**. Respectively, you can use the purchase wherever you're logged in with your gamertag ("system"), or with any gamertag on the console associated with the purchase ("local"). When is this "local" license assigned?

#### Scenario 1

If I make a purchase on a console, is the local license assigned when the content is finished downloading, when the download is initiated, or when the download is first added to the queue?

If I buy an item on console A but don't finish downloading, and later log into console B, will the download automatically queue to redownload on this console B? Accordingly, is the local license then assigned to console B?

#### Scenario 2

If I make a purchase on Xbox.com, is the local license assigned to the first console I log into? Or is it assigned to my home console somehow? Is there no local license automatically assigned at all in this case (unless reassigned with the License Transfer tool)?

Comment: Tricky question... There's gotta be something for technicalities like this on the Xbox site somewhere. If I find something I'll make an answer

Comment: It might be useful to explain why you want to know.  Is your use case specific to a 2+ XBox scenario, or are you thinking of non-XBox devices used with a single XBox?  As you point out, purchases follow your Gamertag whenever connected to Live - which solves the issue for many situations.

Comment: @EBongo: My personal use case is the former (where I'd need to know which console has the license for offline play), but I had generalized the question for general use

Answer (score 1):

## SCENARIO 1:

The license is given at time of download to the system with the **system** license meaning that any user who plays on xbox live has access to the license on that particular machine. Then if you go to Console B and sign in, users playing on Console A would have the DLC and you would be using a "local" or what I would consider to be a "Roaming" license to play the same DLC on Console B. Just because you redownload on B does not invalidate DLC on A.

## Scenario 2:

As Dominik said it would be assigned to the first console that connected with your Gamertag.

To my knowledge there is no method of associating a gamertag with a "Home" xbox. I will usually go reverify all licenses are owned by my personal main xbox by performing a [license transfer](http://youtu.be/LMZXSAzUdfE?t=31s). There used to be a method of doing it in the xbox website but has since be removed.

**EDIT:** This Answers are for the **Xbox 360** not the Xbox One. Xbox one allows the same system and profile license and even identifies "Home" Xbox's. More info can be found at [Xbox's website](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/games/my-home-xbox) and even allows [Sharing](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/xbox-live/xbox-live-gold-sharing-features).

Comment: Evidence to back this up is what's necessary. Otherwise this is just repeating what's been said.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd love to post a video between my girlfriend and I's xbox but at the moment that is not possible. My proof would have to be playing call of duty. I downloaded black ops 2 map packs on her xbox with my season pass then went home and was playing with her. But that was just my first hand experience.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/marketplace-and-purchasing/download-content)
is the closest I could come to finding a real answer. There is almost nothing about this topic on any site but hopefully it helps.

> How do I obtain licenses for content?
>
> Licenses are automatically acquired when you download content. If a
>   license is missing or has become corrupted, you can access the
>   download history on your Xbox 360 console and redownload that content
>   to reacquire a license. This process refreshes existing licenses and
>   does not transfer licenses to a new console, unless the license
>   transfer tool was used first.

So for both your scenarios...

**Scenario 1**

It seems the local license is updated every time you download DLC to an Xbox system. It would give the license to system A since you started it on that one first (Not 100% sure but it makes the most sense)

**Scenario 2**

It would give the license to the first console you download it to with your Account the DLC was purchased on.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is the Xbox you finish the download on is the Xbox it is registered to locally.
Keep this in mind for applications, and games on a roaming console as you should redownload them before starting the application as the game has to add all updates and between the dashboard and game/application screen beggining you can get freezing, passwords not saved, and "Unable to read game disk" messages.

So in starting your game on the roaming console, go to the game DLC section and redownload it. Will not affect the local registered Xbox. Unless you are re-registering your Xbox information to another console, in which you would be going to a settings area on the Xbox, or going to Xbox.com.

In regards to a Netfilx issue somewhere in these forums, I would suggest the same.